# Error using ListObject.Add to create a Table Style

Tags: excel, powershell, comobject

I'm Trying to create a Custom Table(Just like click the 'Format as Table' in the excel bar) with PowerShell and Excel ComObject from a CSV

Here's my code...

```psh
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $true
$Excel.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvFiles.Count
$workbooks = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheets = $workbooks.worksheets
$CSVFullPath = C:\temp.csv
$worksheet = $worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Name = "Temp"

$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $CSVFullPath)
$CellRef = $worksheet.Range("A1")

$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$CellRef)
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $True
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).Refresh()
$worksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

## So Far So good - CSV Imported ##
## My Problem Starts here... ##

$listObject = $worksheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $worksheet.UsedRange, $null),[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes,$null) 

## Then I Received the following error: ##

Exception calling "Add" with "5" argument(s): "A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query
results, protected cells or another table."
At line:1 char:41
+ $ListObject = $WorkSheet.ListObjects.Add <<<< ([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange,$R
ange,$null,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes,$null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I'm have been on it for some time and not found a solution.

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced on that line.  You have a `)` in the middle of the `Add` call after the first `$null`.  Testing the same code in VBA (without the extra `)`) seems to work fine here on some random data.  This might ultimately depend on the data you have on the `Worksheet`.  Does your actual code have the stray `)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you cannot add a `ListObject` to the `Worksheet` with an underlying `QueryTable` still in place.  If you try to do this in normal Excel (non-COM), you will get an error like:

[image]

If you hit `Yes` there and record a macro while it does its work, Excel just deletes the `QueryTable` and adds the `ListObject`.  Deleting the `QueryTable` does not affect the underlying data.

In the VBA world, your code would look like this:

```vb
Sub DeleteQueryTableAndAddListObject()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    ''code up here to create a QueryTable

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = sht.QueryTables.Count To 1 Step -1
        sht.QueryTables(i).Delete
    Next i

    sht.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, sht.UsedRange, , xlYes

End Sub
```

Taking a stab at PowerShell (not my native tongue) you should be able to do:

```
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).Delete()
```

or possibly:

```
$Connector.Delete()
```

since `$Connector` appears to be a valid reference to the `QueryTable` object.